# Usage Rails 3.0 beta 3 without ActiveRecord ORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just installed Rails 3.0 beta 3 in Windows 7.
And started playing with some easy examples

```
   class SignupController < ApplicationController
     def index
       @user = User.new(params[:user])
       if method.post? and @user.save
         redirect_to :root
       end
     end
   end

    class User
      def initialize(params = {})
        @email = params[:email]
        @passw = params[:password]
      end

      def save
      end
    end

<div align="center">
 <% form_for :user do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :email %>
  <%= form.text_field :email %><br />
  <%= form.label :password %>
  <%= form.text_field :password %><br />
  <%= form.submit :Register! %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

When I go to /signup I'm getting this error

> NoMethodError in
>   SignupController#index
>
> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of Array. The error occurred
>   while evaluating nil.[]

Is there a problem with constructor or what's wrong?Please, need your help!
I just won't use ActiveRecord or any other ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another action to handle the post, possibly it is called `create`. This is how I would revise your controller:

```
def index
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if method.post? and @user.save
    redirect_to :root
  end
end
```

The error possibly because when the `index` is displayed, `params` variable had no content.